# xmlHttp.responseText Unknown Error define

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, sql-server, xmlhttprequest

I have create a javascript in an html (using xmlHttp.responseText) page where I am requesting a value from an aspx page that queries for a usernumber of a username in the database (MSSQL). when i load the html (IE8), i got this "Unknown Runtime Error Line: 30". What supposed to be causing the problem? need help. Here is my code:

1. Here is the HTML page and the Javascript:

   ```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function showUsernum(str)
      {
         var xmlHttp;   
          if (str=="")
      {
       document.getElementById("textExists").innerHTML="";
       return;
       }
      if (window.xmlHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlHttp=new xmlHttpRequest();
       }
    else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.xmlHttp");
       }

     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
         if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
         {
       //alert(str);
             document.getElementById("textExists").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
         }
      }

      xmlHttp.open("GET","http://localhost/Base_Data/default.aspx?q="+str,true);
      xmlHttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

   <form action=""  method="post"> 
   <label>UserName
   <input type="text" name="textUser" id="textUser" onchange="showUsernum(this.value)">
   </label>
   </form>
   <br/>
   <div >
   <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
   <label>
   <div id="textExists">Exists?</div>
   </label>
   </form>
   </div>
   </body>
   ```
2. Here is my ASP code.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Expires = -1;
       SqlConnection conn;
               string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["BaseData"].ConnectionString;
               conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
               string sql = "SELECT USERNUM FROM useraccount WHERE USERNAME ='" + Request.QueryString["q"] + "'";
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

               conn.Open();
               string contNm = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
               Response.Write("textExists=" + contNm );

               conn.Close();

     }
   ```

Really appreaciate any response. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `Response.Clear();` before the `Response.Write()` and `Response.End();` afterwards.

Comment: Hi Shadow Wizard, This works for me thanks!

Comment: But I have a question, is it possible that my html page to run out of the server calling the asp page? I test it and its not working..

Comment: Ow, sorry, it still works! Thanks! this saves me alot of time!

Comment: How about the Refresh? how can I do it here. Sorry, very new to this. thanks!

Comment: I added an answer with full code (fixing some other things you didn't mention) what you mean about Refresh? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to assign whole page, including `<html>` tag and everything, into a single DOM element and IE doesn't really like that.

To have the server send only raw HTML without whole document you need to clear the Response. In addition you are not disposing properly of the database objects and you are exposed to SQL Injection attacks, so optimized code would be:

```cs
string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["BaseData"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    conn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT USERNUM FROM useraccount WHERE USERNAME=@user";
    string contNm = "";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", Request.QueryString["q"]);
        contNm = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
    }
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write("textExists=" + contNm);
    Response.End();
    conn.Close();
}
```